# How to use App center environment variables in iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, environment-variables, visual-studio-app-center

I have tried a few things, but I can't get the variables to stick, probably because I am not used to writing Scripts.

The documentation from Appcenter : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/variables/
It says I can only access the environment variables from app center in the build script..

1. I have tried creating a Run Script from Build phases, but no variables is saved no matter what. How do I save an environment variable ? I have tried, export ENVIRONMENT_TEST="abc", but I cant see it afterwards using

   let environments = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["ENVIRONMENT_TEST"]
2. I found a similar issue: [Using Microsoft App Center environment variables in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54266481/using-microsoft-app-center-environment-variables-in-ios)

here the solution is to save the environment variable $ENVIRONMENT_VARIBLE to a file and read from it later. So now im trying to save to a new plist file. This works locally, but not from a device. I believe its because the path is different. I use:

```
plutil -replace somekey -string somevalue1 ${SOURCE_ROOT}/AppName/AppcenterValues.plist
```

Any ideas for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the predefined variables are different, instead of `SOURCE_ROOT` use `APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY`. You script will end up something like this:

```sh
plutil -replace somekey -string somevalue1 $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/AppName/AppcenterValues.plist
```

You can find more examples on the official `AppCenter` github repository in  following link:

https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/blob/master/sample-build-scripts/react-native/version-name/appcenter-pre-build.sh